# scrapy crawling at depth not working

Tags: python, scrapy

I am writing scrapy code to crawl first page and one additional depth of given webpage

Somehow my crawler doesn't enter additional depth. Just crawls given starting urls and ends its operation.

I added filter_links callback function but even thts not getting called so clearly rules are getting ignored. what can be possible reason and what can i change to make it follow rules

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from crawlWeb.items import CrawlwebItem
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
class DmozSpider(CrawlSpider):
name = "premraj"
start_urls = [
    "http://www.broadcom.com",
    "http://www.qualcomm.com"
]
rules = [Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(), callback='parse',process_links="process_links",follow=True)]
def parse(self, response):
    #print dir(response)
    #print dir(response)
    item=CrawlwebItem()

    item["html"]=response.body
    item["url"]=response.url
    yield item
def process_links(self,links):
    print links
    print "hey!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a Warning box in the [CrawlSpider documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawling-rules). It says:

> When writing crawl spider rules, avoid using parse as callback, since
>   the CrawlSpider uses the parse method itself to implement its logic.
>   So if you override the parse method, the crawl spider will no longer
>   work.

Your code does probably not work as expected because you do use `parse` as callback.

Comment: Thank you! thats the problem!